# xmlファイルのmongodbへのinsert

Tags: python, xml, mongodb

xmlファイルをmongodbへinsertしたいと考えております
またxmlのデータ型を定義したxsdファイルが別途あるのですが
このデータ型通りにmongodbへinsertしたいです

現在pythonを利用してxmlファイルを読み取りpythonの辞書型に変更して
mongodbへのinsertを考えておりますが辞書型にする際にxsdに定義されたデータ型
に合うように辞書型にする簡単な方法はありますでしょうか？

xmltodict　https://pypi.org/project/xmltodict/
というライブラリを利用すると簡単に辞書型に変換してくれるのですが
データがすべてstr型になります

pythonを必ずしも利用する必要はありませんが、
比較的得意な言語がpythonです

どうぞ宜しくお願いします

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pythonの [xmlschema](https://github.com/brunato/xmlschema) というライブラリーを使うと、xsdデータを読み込んで型のチェエクして、数値は int, float に変換してくれます。日付情報の方は、string型になるような設定になっています、それを修正して日付情報を`date`,`datetime`型で取得するサンプルを書いておきます。

xmlschema/validators/simple_types.py に`datetime`をインポートして

```
from datetime import date, datetime
```

の432行目あたりを以下のように変更してdate型及びdatetime型に変換するコードを追加します。

```
if self.prefixed_name == 'xs:date':
    try:
        ts = _text.split('-')
        yield date(int(ts[0]), int(ts[1]), int(ts[2]))
    except (ValueError, IndexError) as err:
        # エラー処理
        yield None
    return
if self.prefixed_name == 'xs:datetime':
    try:
        yield datetime.strptime(_text, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    except ValueError as err:
        # エラー処理
        yield None
    return            
# 以下のコードの前におく
try:
    result = self.to_python(_text)
except (ValueError, DecimalException) as err:
.....
```

ソースコードに手を入れるのであれば、`xmltodict`の方でも同じようにできます。自分でキーの型情報を作成する必要がありあますが、普通は `string` 以外に int, float, date, datetime ぐらいしか出てこないので、`xmltodict`を使った方がコードがシンプルなだけに楽に処理できるケースが多いと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。日付の形式がw3c-dtfだったので"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z"としてpython3.7.0b4にして無事動作しました

Answer (score 0):

xmltodictを使って辞書型にして、その後で問題があれば修正したらどうでしょうか。

サンプルとしてはこんな感じです。

```
import xmltodict
xml = '''<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
<country name="Liechtenstein">
    <rank>1</rank>
    <year>2008</year>
    <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
    <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
</country>
<country name="Singapore">
    <rank>4</rank>
    <year>2011</year>
    <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
    <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
</country>
</data>'''

data_dict = xmltodict.parse(xml)
for country in data_dict['data']['country']:
    country['rank'] = int(country['rank'])
    country['year'] = int(country['year'])
    country['gdppc'] = int(country['gdppc'])
```

もし、これで対応できないようであれば、xml.etree.ElementTree モジュールを使ってXMLデータを解析して、辞書型への変換は自分でした方がいいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます．ご提案方法ですと，項目数が少ない場合には良いのですが項目数が非常に多いので厳しいです．xmlschema[link](https://pypi.org/project/xmlschema/)を用いるとxsdファイルを意識してpythonのデータ型にしてくれるようです．ただ，日付情報がstring型になってしまうので難儀しています．

Comment: 一応、xmlschema を使って日付情報をdata型にする方法書いておきます。